# What is the Importance of the main() Function in the Ring programming language?

Tags: scripting-language

All C language programs must have a main() function. It's the core of every program but what was the purpose of including the "Main" function in the Ring programming language ?

what is the difference between this program

```
see "hello, world!"
```

and another one contains the Main function!

```
func main
    see "hello, world!"
```

Is this because someone would make a lot of statements as a preparation then use the "Main" function to start the execution of the real logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it to use the Local scope instead of the Global scope.

Example

```
x = 10
myfunc()
See "X value = " + X  # here i expect that x will be (10)
                # but i will get another value (6) because myfunc() uses x !
Func myfunc
  for x = 1 to 5
     See x + nl
  next
```

Output : X value = 6

```
Func Main 
  x = 10
  myfunc()
  See "X value = " + X                         

Func myfunc
  for x = 1 to 5
    See x + nl
  next
```

Output: X value = 10

Comment: I got it, Thank you for your answer.